# VBA to copy and count words of a specific column and move them to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to achieve is a VBA code to copy and count all words which are in a column and move it to another sheet sorted by hight frequency to lower. The number of rows can be different. See below:

```
Column1:
Finance
SAP
Finance
HR
Design
Design
HR
People
SAP
SAP
```

New sheet:

```
SAP 3
Finance 2
Design 2
SAP 2
HR 2
People 1
```

Any idea how to do this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the test approach will be to create pivot table and add row Lables and count of the column.

http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

this will let you know how to create pivot and do the needful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This will work, just need to sort the 'List' worksheet on Column B after running this:

```
Sub Count_Sort()
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim ws As String
Dim c As Range

ws = ActiveSheet.Name
lastRow = LastUsedRow
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
ActiveSheet.Name = "List"
Sheets(ws).Activate
Set c = Range("A1")
Set d = Sheets("List").Range("A1")
Do While Not IsEmpty(c)
    Do While Not IsEmpty(d)

        If c.Value = d.Value Then

            d.Offset(0, 1).Value = d.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
            Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Set d = Sheets("List").Range("A1")
Loop
End Sub


Public Function LastUsedRow()
LastUsedRow = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: I'd recommend you add some comments in the code, or outside of the code, that helps explain what it is that your code is doing. This helps the person asking the question understand what needs to be done and learn something, rather than just take an answer and plug it in to their source.

Comment: @zada thank you. how can have it sorted automatically giving headers to the 2 columns?